# File sent over NetworkStream is received corrupted C#

Tags: c#, filestream, file-transfer, networkstream

My goal is to send a file over a TCP connection using NetworkStream.
I first send the length of the data I'm going to send, and then I use a filestream and a binary writter to send the data byte by byte.

While debugging the process, I found out that some '0' bytes are being put at the beggining of the file on the receiving end.
For example, the base file's content `azertyuiop` is received as `azerty` (4 spaces replacing `uiop`), causing files like images to be corrupted.

The code I've got so far :
(Where br is a BinaryReader and bw is a BinaryWriter)

Sender:

```
using (var readStream = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open))
{
    // Send the data length first
    bw.Write(new FileInfo(fileLocation).Length);
    bw.Flush();

    var buffer = new byte[1];
    while (readStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1) > 0)
    {
          bw.Write(buffer[0]);
          bw.Flush();
    }
}
```

Receiver:

```
// Get data length
var dataLength = br.ReadInt32();

using (var fs = new FileStream(newFileLocation, FileMode.Create))
{
    var buffer = new byte[1];
    for(int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)
    {
        br.Read(buffer, 0, 1);
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099875/sending-messages-and-files-over-networkstream to see how they are sending and receiving the length of the data.

Comment: Not part of your problem but your reading and writing of a single byte at a time is very inefficient. Use larger buffers and the result of your Read calls to see how much you need to write.

Comment: especially flushing every byte, dont do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be the following:

```
bw.Write(new FileInfo(fileLocation).Length);
...
var dataLength = br.ReadInt32();
```

The `Length` property is actually of type `long` (8 bytes). But you are reading the value as `Int32` (4 bytes), leaving the other 4 bytes in the stream.

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question : is there a better than using a byte array of size 1 ? Maybe more size ?

Comment: Yes, you should increase your buffer size to a few kilobytes and adjust your loop accordingly. When reading the stream, pay attention to the return value of the Read() method, as it actually returns the number of bytes read. That would help you determine when you have reached the end of the stream, even if your buffer is larger than the last portion that was read. That way you may even avoid using the data length value altogether, and just check for the end of the stream instead.

Answer (score 1):

fileinfo.length is a long not an int32